# Combining geom_bar with geom_line in one plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have tried to combine 2 plots into 1 plot. But the geom_line doesn't show up and, the y-axis to the right is not in %.

The geom_bar shows what i want it to, but the geom_line does not show up in the ggplot.
The geom_line is a %, and shows the relationship between BV and FV, % = BG/FV.

My table as it looks like in Excel.

Comma for Europeans:

| Aar | Type | mia_kr | BG |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2004 | FV | 1918050 | 0,489221 |
| 2004 | BG | 938350,0583 |  |
| 2005 | FV | 2312210 | 0,447918 |
| 2005 | BG | 1035680,125 |  |
| 2006 | FV | 2842071 | 0,416046 |
| 2006 | BG | 1182431,742 |  |
| 2007 | FV | 2910107 | 0,447245 |
| 2007 | BG | 1301530,525 |  |

All those who doesn't use comma:

| Aar | Type | mia_kr | BG |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2004 | FV | 1918050 | 0.489221 |
| 2004 | BG | 938350.0583 |  |
| 2005 | FV | 2312210 | 0.447918 |
| 2005 | BG | 1035680.125 |  |
| 2006 | FV | 2842071 | 0.416046 |
| 2006 | BG | 1182431.742 |  |
| 2007 | FV | 2910107 | 0.447245 |
| 2007 | BG | 1301530.525 |  |

My code:

```
    library(ggplot2)
SAMLET <- data.frame(Aar=c(2004, 2004, 2005, 2005, 2006, 2006, 2007, 2007),
                  Type=c(FV, BG, FV, BG,FV, BG,FV, BG,),
                  mia_kr=c(1918050,938350.0583, 2312210, 1035680.125, 2842071, 1182431.742, 2910107, 1301530.525))
SAMLET_2 <- data.frame(Aar=c(2004, 2005, 2006, 2007,),
BG=c(0.489221, ,0.447918, ,0.416046, , 0.447245, ))



ggplot() + 
  geom_bar(mapping = aes(x= SAMLET$Aar, y= SAMLET$mia_kr, fill = SAMLET$Type), stat="identity",position = "identity")+
  geom_line(mapping = aes(x= SAMLET_2$Aar, y = SAMLET_2$BG),size = 2, color = "blue") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::format_format(big.mark = ".", decimal.mark = ",", scientific = FALSE),
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(~ ./4,labels = scales::format_format(big.mark = ".", decimal.mark = ",", scientific = FALSE) ))
```

[Shows the barplots with 2 y-axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QAGQ3.png)

[How it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BgvIV.png)

Comment: Please, provide all the code you used, including that used to read the data into R. The data (preferably the simplest possible needed to reproduce the problem) in readable format so that any of us trying to answer your question can reproduce the problem locally. Please, also simplify the code so anything not relevant to triggering the problem you describe is left at it's default.

Comment: It should be possible to make locally now. Just copy paste the table into your own excel-file.

Comment: Please read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

Comment: Should be fixed now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = Aar)) + 
   geom_col(aes(y = mia_kr, fill = Type)) + 
   geom_line(aes(y = BG*max(mia_kr), group =Type))  +
   scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::format_format(big.mark = ".", decimal.mark = ",", scientific = FALSE),
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(~ ./max(df$mia_kr)))
```

[image]

Note that the line values are upscaled according the max `mia_kr` value.

Comment: The bars should not be added together, but lay on top of each other. To show FV is bigger than BG.